# React native ios observedTopOfStack

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactive-programming

I just started to build ios app in React Native.
I dont know I am getting this weird kind of error while using TabbarIOS

> index.ios.bundle:25577 If waiting for observedTopOfStack to reach requestedTopOfStack, the only valid observedTopOfStack should be requestedTopOfStack.

Can anyone guide me why is this error coming up?
Thanks

Comment: I had this error once, you're probably calling something over and over in your code like an unlimited recursive function. Check namespaces or naming collisions, where your calling the methods etc...

Comment: Thanks @AKADER, I figured it out. NavigatorIOS was calling over and over.